# Bash function hangs once conditions are met

Tags: bash, function, freeze

All,

I am trying to run a bash script that kicks off several sub processes. The processes redirect to their own log files and I must kick them off in parallel. To do this i have written a check_procs procedure, that monitors for the number of processes using the same parent PID. Once the number reaches 1 again, the script should continue. However, it seems to just hang. I am not sure why, but the code is below:

```
check_procs() {
  while true; do

    mypid=$$
    backup_procs=`ps -eo ppid | grep -w $mypid | wc -w`

    until [ $backup_procs == 1 ]; do
      echo $backup_procs
      sleep 5
      backup_procs=`ps -eo ppid | grep -w $mypid | wc -w`
    done

  done

}
```

This function is called after the processes are kicked off, and I can see it echoing out the number of processes, but then the echoing stops (suggesting the function has completed since the process count is now 1, but then nothing happens, and I can see the script is still in the process list of the server. I have to kill it off manually. The part where the function is called is below:

```
 for ((i=1; i <= $threads; i++)); do

  <Some trickery here to generate $cmdfile and $logfile>

  nohup rman target / cmdfile=$cmdfile log=$logfile &

  x=$(($x+1))

done

check_procs
```

$threads is a command line parameter passed to the script, and is a small number like 4 or 6. These are kicked off using nohup, as shown. When the IF in check_procs is satisfied, everything hangs instead of executing the remainder of the script. What's wrong with my function?

Comment: Stick some `echo`s throughout, to debug. `echo "before until loop, backup_procs == $backup_procs"`, `echo "in until loop"`, `"echo "after until loop"` etc. I suspect your `while true` is going forever.

Comment: You never exit your while true loop. You should add a break somewhere

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script to debug the bash script

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. I expected this was the case, so placed an exit in there, which did not work. I then realised I'd put it after the second 'done' which was of course outside the while loop! I corrected this and it sent me back to the command line, so progress. I just need an appropriate break in there now, but not sure what?

Comment: @Pawamoy I see you mean I literally need to type break. D'oh! This worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but it is not expected? Your outer loop runs forever, there is no exit point. Unless the process count increases again the outer loop runs infinitely (without any delay which is not recommended).

Comment: I figured this was the issue, and forgot to mention that I had placed an exit after the inner loop, but this didn't fix the problem. It still continued to hang. I have since realised that my exit was in the wrong place, and therefore removed it. I now realise I need to put a break in of some kind, but not sure what?

Comment: thanks for this, I have seen the light and have added a break into the while loop. Such a simple error, and it seems so silly now!

Comment: I often have the same strange blind spot in my own code. :) BTW: Maybe you should add `sleep` to the outer loop to avoid running the loop at full speed if $backup_procs == 1  (resource eater).

Comment: I noticed you mentioned that. Where would I put the sleep? There's a sleep in my until loop, which slows that down, but $backup_procs == 1 I want it to run at full speed into the next part of the script.

Comment: If you exit if backup_procs == 1 anyway, then no need to sleep. But what is the purpose of the outer loop then? why is it necessary?

Comment: Agree, the `while true` loop in not needed here!

Comment: hmmm, in my head the inner loop had to be in its own loop, so it'll continuously loop around and re-set the backup_procs parameter, but if I'm doing that in the inner loop then I guess you're right...I'll change it and see how we go!